# DRCSIM: When will pelvis height control work with STAND and MANIPULATE modes of BDI Sim interface?

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using latest drcsim-nightly build, the system is using Sim Interface 1.0.8.

When will the next version be released? (I see 1.1.0 is in testing)

When will the use_desired pelvis_height control start working?
(It does not seem to impact MANIPULATE in the current release.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2627/drcsim:-when-will-pelvis-height-control-work-with-stand-and-manipulate-modes-of-bdi-sim-interface?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's supported in 1.1.0, and pending [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/220/atlassiminterface-110-integration) review and merge.  Please see the [DRCSim RoadMap](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap) for details on ROS API changes.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-05-02**:
The road map doesn't give an expected date.  I presume it will be released prior to the DARPA "code freeze" May 17th.  Will 2.6 (including 1.1.0 interface) be released prior to that date for testing?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-05-07**:
We'll make a release after Qual's over.  For now, you can get it by sudo apt-get install drcsim-nightly.